# C - Using argv for commands

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, argv

Currently I am implementing a simple binary search tree and to add, delete, search, or whatever command I want, I would like to enter it in the command line then perform the function.

So the following code would insert the integer 6 into the binary tree, see if it was added" then delete it. Then proceed to traverse through the tree post-order. (That was added to show it's not just strings and integers that need to be implemented - as a reference)

```
"insert" 6 
"search" 6
"delete" 6
"traverse" "post"
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a **comparison warning** between pointer and integer when trying to determine which function to call when relating to the arg

```
int main(int c, char *argv[2]) {

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
}  * node;

    /* This is irrelevant and the function is in a different file */
createNode(1);
createNode(2);
createNode(3);
createNode(4);
createNode(5);
createNode(6);
createNode(7);
createNode(8);

    /* comparison warnings when deciding WHICH method to call based on the command given */
if (argv[0] == "quit") quit();
if (argv[0] == "insert") insert(argv[1]);
if (argv[0] == "delete") delete(argv[1]); 
if (argv[0] == "search") search(argv[1]);
if (argv[0] == "empty") empty();
```

}

Comment: you can't do string comparision in C using `"asdf"=="asdf"`, you have to use `strcmp()`

Answer (score 2):

Notice the argument definition:

```
char *argv[]
```

Which reads: "`argv` is an array of pointers to `char`. So `argv[0]` is of type `char *`, while `q` is of type `char`. Basically, you're comparing a character with a string.

You can compare strings with `strcmp`, which returns 0 iff the strings are equal:

```
    if(strcmp(argv[0], "quit") == 0)
        ...
```

Also, `argv[0]` usually holds the name of your program. The first argument is stored in `argv[1]`.

EDIT: I swear I saw `argv[0]=='q'` somewhere... The first part of the answer is irreleant after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of `main()` normally is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

And the the first argument, i.e. `argv[0]`, is the name of your program, and `argv[1]` is the first argument you given on the command line to your program.

And to compare two strings, you should using `strcmp()` from `<string.h>` instead of `==`, this is cause of the warnings you mentioned in your question. Because `argv[0]` or `argv[1]` is a pointer to `char`, and `'q'` is a `char` (it will be casted to `int` automatically).

Therefore, you should use something like the following in your code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "quit") == 0) quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is typically declared as

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

`argc` indicates how many command line arguments were entered by the user, and hence how many valid pointers are in the `argv` array.  The first pointer in the `argv` array is typically the name of the program or the full path to the program.

You should always check `argc` before using the pointers in `argv`.  If the code requires the user to enter 2 parameters after the command name, then the code should check that `argc == 3` and should print a `usage` message and exit if argc is not 3.

For the program listed in the question, the expected arguments are

```
argv[0]   name or path of the program
argv[1]   command: "quit", "insert", etc.
argv[2]   additional argument for the command
```

but the last two can only be used if `argc == 3`.